# Use generated JAXB class with lists in web servise wsdl/xsd

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, wsdl

I have class definition in xsd file. I generated class using JAXB binding. For lists I haven't setters.

After that, I used this classes in my web services. I created wsdl + xsd for service. But ... in xsd I haven't some field definition (for lists, because I haven't setters for these).

How can I generate correctly wsdl + xsd for my classes?

Netbeans 7.3.1 + Glassfish

**Sample code:**
Base XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:element name="A">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="B">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="FIELD1" type="xs:dateTime">
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I do JAX binding, so It generated class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "b"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "A")
public class A {

@XmlElement(name = "B", required = true)
protected List<A.B> b;

public List<A.B> getB() {
    if (b == null) {
        b = new ArrayList<A.B>();
    }
    return this.b;
}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "field1"
})
public static class B {

    @XmlElement(name = "FIELD1", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar field1;

    public XMLGregorianCalendar getFIELD1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setFIELD1(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
        this.field1 = value;
    }
}
```

}

As You can see, there is no setter for b field...

And I use it in web service:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") A txt) {
    return "Hello " + txt + " !";
}
```

So finnaly, I have wsdl + xsd, with A class, but with no field:

```
  <xs:complexType name="a"><xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

JAXB doesn't generate setters for Collections. You can access your list with its getter then use the list methods to modify it.

Example:

```
txt.getB().add(new B());
```

**Source:** See [here](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_2_2_12_5-Content-A-Homogeneous-List-of-Elements.html#Content:%20A%20Homogeneous%20List%20of%20Elements) for details.

### EDIT due to comment:

After further analysis of the question, I think what you're looking for is the [JiBX's BindGen Tool](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/fromcode/bindgen.html). It is a "tool used to generate a binding definition and matching schema definition from existing Java code".

Hope this helps you further with your problem.

Comment: Yeah I know it... But my question is how to generate correctly xsd file for my web service from JAXB generated class.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. I've edited my answer to reflect what I understand from your formulation. Hope this helps.